# How to copy a string from a <div> and past in an <input>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Code of **Note** i want copy is : `<strong title="Note VF" class="note-a-copier" style="cursor: pointer;" data-clipboard-text="7.6">7.6</strong>`

I copy the **Note** with : `data-clipboard-text`

Normally past on :

HTML :

```html
<select>
<option id="note-a-coller"></option>
</select>
```

JavaScript :

```js
<script>
const btnsnote = document.getElementsByClassName('note-a-copier');
for(btn of btnsnote) {
    btn.addEventListener(\'click\', elt => {
    const input = document.getElementById('note-a-coller');
    select.value = elt.target.dataset.clipboardText;

    return false;
    }, false);
}
</script>
```

But when I click on the note, it should stick directly in the  but it doesn't work.

Example Working Code : https://jsfiddle.net/rjds289g/

```js
const btnsadp = document.getElementsByClassName('adp-a-copier');
for(btn of btnsadp)
{
 btn.addEventListener('click', elt => {
  const input = document.getElementById('adp-a-coller');
  input.value = elt.target.dataset.clipboardText;

  return false;
 }, false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Copy : <div class="adp-a-copier" data-clipboard-text="2001" style="cursor: pointer;">2001</div>

Past : <input type="text" size="40" name="annee" value="" id="adp-a-coller" required />
```

On **JSFiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/rjds289g/3/

I want like this, but with **< select >** and i don't know how to do this, so if anyone can help me :)

Answer (score 2):

- Select value will change with any value inside of it .. in your case the value isn't an option in a select so you need to append it first

```js
const btnsadp = document.getElementsByClassName('adp-a-copier');
for(btn of btnsadp)
{
  btn.addEventListener('click', elt => {
    var The_Select = document.getElementById('adp-a-coller'),
        The_Text = document.createTextNode(elt.target.dataset.clipboardText),
        The_option = document.createElement("OPTION");
    The_option.appendChild(The_Text);
    The_Select.appendChild(The_option);
    The_Select.value = elt.target.dataset.clipboardText;
    return false;
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Copy : <div class="adp-a-copier" data-clipboard-text="2001" style="cursor: pointer;">2001</div>

Past : <select id="adp-a-coller"><option>1</option></select>
```

And this is the jquery version <sup>for me it's much easier to work with</sup>

```js
$(document).on('click' , '.adp-a-copier' , function(){
  var $this = $(this),
      text = $this.data('clipboard-text');
  if(!$this.hasClass('appended')){
    $this.addClass('appended');
    $('#adp-a-coller').append('<option value="'+text+'">'+text+'</option>').val(text);
  }else{
    $('#adp-a-coller').val(text);
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Copy : <div class="adp-a-copier" data-clipboard-text="2001" style="cursor: pointer;">2001</div>
Copy : <div class="adp-a-copier" data-clipboard-text="2003" style="cursor: pointer;">2003</div>
Copy : <div class="adp-a-copier" data-clipboard-text="2005" style="cursor: pointer;">2005</div>

Past : <select id="adp-a-coller"></select>
```

Explanation : I used the `appended` class in jquery snippet to append the text just one time to the select even you keep clicking it will remain just one append

Comment: @Machou you're totally welcome .. And please check my updated answer the jquery part ..

Comment: I've seen, indeed I clearly prefer the version with jQuery, I've adapted it and I've rewritten everything with your version, it's much cleaner and faster :)

Answer (score 0):

Read about how to fill a select with JS. the logic is easy. 
You just have to add the div content in an array and after it refill combo with your array content